# When to separate code into new assemblies (DLL's)

Tags: .net, design-patterns, c#-4.0, architecture, anti-patterns

I work as part of a team creating an enterprise application that will be used in a new C# .NET Windows Application and a Web Application of the same.  One of the other developers likes to separate things out into separate projects a bit more than I.  His answer is always "separate of concerns" which I'm not sure I agree with.

My theory is you create separate assemblies when that code is capable of being shared by other consumers.  Separation of concerns should be handled by namespaces.  It can be an additional effort/challenge/nightmare to distribute an application with a large number of assemblies from versioning, obfuscation, etc.  So it concerns me and I'm trying to find out what the rule of thumb is for when code is broken out into its own assembly.

What is your rule of thumb for separating code into other assemblies vs. using namespaces and other organization techniques within an application?  Is there any guidance on this or patterns/practices that I can read to either say "yeah, he's right" or "please read this".

Thank you.

Comment: Before you begin coding.  Design first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have a communication issue, or an issue with nomenclature because, separation of concerns, generally means something different.

Strictly speaking, separation of concerns, deals with things like the single responsibility principle, in that, each class kinda deals with it's own domain. The single responsibility principle states that a class, should only have one reason to change.

Some examples of separation of concerns are view and model abstraction patterns such as MVC or MVVM. Where each component, be it the view or model, deals with user interface abstraction or data and validation, but not both.

Splitting up code into separate assemblies is a good practice when the code can be shared between multiple projects (like you yourself already pointed out). Simply structuring code can  be done by using different namespaces.

When you have a lot of code, assemblies are a natural way of grouping code and when you managed code on different levels and have very controlled points of extensibility and want to lock that down, assemblies provide that level of isolation.

Comment: Agree, seperation of concerns has nothing to do with Assemblies but is instead related to what code you put in what classes.  The decision of how to organize your units of delivery (the dlls and exes) should be done based the some set of objectives (ease of install, sharing of common objects) and then analysized, designed, and implemented just like any other task.  The use of namespaces helps to make your application code largely unaware of the units of delivery.

Answer (score 4):

In part due to the reasoning already provided by Shark (versioning, and recompile/replacement of select assemblies consumed by a larger application). But also I tend to create assemblies when doing so forms an independently useful and complete code unit.

For example, I might be creating a parsing unit to parse HTML (a fool's errand, I know . . . this is an example!) for use within a larger application. If the functionality of HTMLParsingUnit is relatively complete (in other words, not specific to the larger application) then I would likely create this in its own assembly both for re-use by other code, and to encapsulate versioning/changes.

Similarly, I once had to create a mapping and provide classes of DataTypes from ASNI SQL to .NET CLR types. I created an independent DLL for this, as I figured it might come in handy in other projects. Obviously, doing so meant abstracting the components of the assembly comepltely, but this made maintenence easier. Ultimately, I DID re-use this assembly in several different projects.

Just my two cents . . .

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb is to always separate code in different code libraries first and foremost if that DLL can be consumed by other applications.

But another consideration for me is with versioning.  If a grouping of code will often times be improved upon/scaled, to me it is easier to have that as a separate DLL, so the other DLLs/exe in the project are absolutely ignorant to the changes, unless the calls are also altered.

I think those are the two main reasons for separating code into different DLLs.